# How to make a Firefox add-on panel always on top and able to change opacity?

Tags: firefox-addon

[image: http://i961.photobucket.com/albums/ae98/tungtungxen/Untitleds_zpsdfm0wwyu.png]

How to make panel like the above image: Always on top and can change opacity?

Comment: Set `level` to `parent` if you are not using addon sdk you can use this snippet: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9445992

Comment: Where did you find this? It's not on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel ?

Comment: Me @SebastianBlask ?

Comment: @Noitidart yes, sorry for not using @ before

Comment: @SebastianBlask No prob, I actually wrote that and use that from scratchpad: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oo4STWceGTM